# How to override Nextjs 13 `src/app/layout.tsx`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I want to implement a custom layout for my `/admin` and its children routes (includes `/admin/*`). How can I override the main/root only for the `/admin/*` routes?

So in the example bellow I want the `/` and `/profile` implements the layout from the main layout (`src/app/layout.tsx`) but only for `/admin` it should implement a different layout.

[image]

Is it really possible to implement such thing in Nextjs? And how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `layout.tsx` file in the admin folder. This way you can override the main/root for the /admin/* routes. For example,

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function AdminLayout({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```